# Eliminar el borde de color de los input y texarea con foco

Tags: html, css

La problematica es la siguiente, se crea un input tipo texto, se quita el borde con CSS, pero a la hora de seleccionar el elemento para escribir en él, aparece un borde,¿como quitarlo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder quitar el borde de un input o texarea a la hora de estar escrbiendo en ellos, es necesario utilizar outline en CSS:

```
.clasepredeterminada {
   outline:0 none;
}
```

Espero poder ayudar a alguien con esto, saludos.

Más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero en tu pregunta deberías haber puesto un [example] para que te hubieran podido ayudar mejor, pues resolvemos problemas con código y un escenario delimitado por el mismo, sino tu pregunta podría ser cerrada por esa falta de información y por ser susceptible de opiniones.